# How do you write a parameterized where-in raw sql query in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

How do you write a parameterized where-in raw sql query in Entity Framework? I've tried the following:

```
string dateQueryString = String.Join(",", chartModelData.GetFormattedDateList());
//Dates returned in format of 20140402,20140506,20140704

const string selectQuery = 
    @"SELECT 
         MAX(DATA_SEQ) AS MaxSeq, MIN(DATA_SEQ) AS MinSeq, COUNT(1) AS TotSampleCnt
      FROM SPCDATA_TB
      WHERE DATA_WDATE IN @DateParam  
      AND LINE_CODE = @LineCode
      AND MODEL_NO = @ModelNumber
      AND LOT_NO = @LotNumber
      AND EQUIP_NO LIKE @EquipNumber";

SPCDataSeqCntInfo dataSeqCntInfo = _dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<SPCDataSeqCntInfo>(
      selectQuery,
      new SqlParameter("@DateParam",   dateQueryString),
      new SqlParameter("@LineCode",    chartModelData.LineCode),
      new SqlParameter("@ModelNumber", chartModelData.ModelNum),
      new SqlParameter("@EquipNumber", equipmentNumber),
      new SqlParameter("@LotNumber",   chartModelData.LotNum)
  ).SingleOrDefault() ?? new SPCDataSeqCntInfo();
```

But as expected, it throws an error on DateParam because it's expecting a single value.

Comment: `@DateParam` shall be a comma-separated string representing the dates you wish to look for in the set, then it shall also be delimited by parenthesis.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This isn't a problem specific to entity-framework, you can solve it by generating your own parameter names dynamically.

```
var parameters = new List<SqlParameter> {
    new SqlParameter("@DateParam", dateQueryString),
    new SqlParameter("@LineCode", chartModelData.LineCode),
    new SqlParameter("@ModelNumber", chartModelData.ModelNum),
    new SqlParameter("@EquipNumber", equipmentNumber),
    new SqlParameter("@LotNumber", chartModelData.LotNum)   
};

var dateParameters = chartModelData
    .GetFormattedDateList()
    .Select((date, index) => new SqlParameter("@date" + index, date));
    .ToList();

parameters.AddRange(dateParameters);
    
var inValues = string.Join(", ", dateParameters.Select(p => p.ParameterName));

var query = @"SELECT MAX(DATA_SEQ) AS MaxSeq, 
   MIN(DATA_SEQ) AS MinSeq, 
   COUNT(1) AS TotSampleCnt
   FROM SPCDATA_TB
   WHERE DATA_WDATE IN (" + inValues + @")  
   AND LINE_CODE = @LineCode
   AND MODEL_NO = @ModelNumber
   AND LOT_NO = @LotNumber
   AND EQUIP_NO LIKE @EquipNumber";

var myResult = _dbContext.Database
    .SqlQuery<SPCDataSeqCntInfo>(query, parameters.ToArray());
```

The resulting query sent to SQL-Server will look like the following:

```
SELECT 
   MAX(DATA_SEQ) AS MaxSeq, 
   MIN(DATA_SEQ) AS MinSeq, 
   COUNT(1) AS TotSampleCnt
FROM SPCDATA_TB
WHERE DATA_WDATE IN (@date0, @date1, @date2)  
AND LINE_CODE = @LineCode
AND MODEL_NO = @ModelNumber
AND LOT_NO = @LotNumber
AND EQUIP_NO LIKE @EquipNumber
```

Generally, you want to avoid doing string manipulation when writing queries, however, I believe this example is safe from sql-injection.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you would write your query in SQL.

```
select *
    from MyTable
    where dateColumn in ('2014-01-01', '2014-02-01', '2014-03-01')
```

So one shall not expect otherwise than having to represent this string entirely delimited by parenthesis.

```
var dateQueryString = string.Join(",", chartModelData.GetFormattedDateList());
// Dates shall be returned as DateTime.ToShortDateTimeString() as follows:
// '2014-01-01', '2014-02-01', '2014-03-01'
```

Then only remains to wrap it in parenthesis.

```
var sql = @"select max(data_seq)    as MaxSeq
                    , min(data_seq) as MinSeq
                    , count(1)      as TotSampleCnt
                from spcdata_tb
                where data_wadate in (@DateParam)
                    and line_code  =  @LineCode
                    and model_no   =  @ModelNumber
                    and lot_no     =  @LotNumber
                    and equip_no like @EquipNumber";
```

Provide the parameters values for each named parameter, and voilà! This shall do it!

Answer (score 0):

I'd write a stored proc instead which accepts your parameters, then add the proc to your edmx.

Then, in the edmx -> Model Browser -> Function Imports -> ... change the return type of the stored proc to SPCDataSeqCntInfo.

Entity framework will then take care of passing in your parameters.

e.g.

```
public static List<SPCDataSeqCntInfo> GetSPCDataSeqCntInfo(DateTime dateParam, string lineCode, int modelNum, int equipmentNumber, int lotNum)
{
    using (var db = new NameOfMyEntites())
    {
        return db.sp_GetSPCDataSeqCntInfo(dateParam, lineCode, modelNum, equipmentNumber, lotNum).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Alright. I guess that's a fair alternative, but is there absolutely no way to accomplish what I'm trying to do without resorting into stored procedure? Just for the sake of curiosity.

Comment: Have a look at using _dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand instead.