# Setting WHERE condition to use Ids.Contains() in ExecuteSqlCommand()

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, dbcontext

I'm using Entity Framework and I want to perform a bulk update. It is way too inefficient to load each row, update those rows, and then save them back to the database.

So I'd prefer to use `DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand()`. But how can I use this method to update all those rows with an ID contained in my list of IDs?

Here's what I have so far.

```
IEnumerable<int> Ids;
DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("UPDATE Messages SET Viewed = 1 WHERE Id IN (@list)", Ids);
```

I realize I could manually build a string with the correct query, but I'd prefer to pass my parameters as is generally recommended.

Is there any way to make that happen?

Comment: I'd suggest looking into how Table-Valued Parameters work (though TVPs are used with stored procedures, not written commands). There should be a bunch of questions about this. e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030848/how-to-pass-user-defined-table-type-as-stored-procedured-parameter-in-c-sharp). Outside of that, I think you'd have to pass the list as a string and split it in some way (e.g. a string split function) or use a LIKE statement. There's also a bunch of questions about this, too, so it should be easy to find something that meets your requirements.

Comment: @ZLK: Thanks but I'm really not sure how Table-Valued Parameters can be used here.

Comment: The question I linked has a link to a short example of how you might achieve this: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22392/SQL-Server-Table-Valued-Parameters (I don't believe there's a way to do it with a simple executesqlcommand statement, but I may be wrong). Essentially, you'd need to create a table type (with an INT column), create a stored procedure that takes a TVP of that type as a parameter, then execute the stored procedure by passing a data table with your values in it.

Comment: What's the error you get if you run your code now? You didn't specify (although I can presume it why it fails because there may not be a serializer for List or IEnumerable into one of the `DbType`s in `DbParameter`)

Comment: @MarkC.: To be honest, I didn't even run it. $500.00 says there's no way it would parse that as I want. Well okay, I just tried it. It didn't seem to raise an exception, but it didn't seem to do anything either.

Comment: It had to of done something? Can you enabling logging and debug it?

Comment: @MarkC.: I don't seem to have the needed permissions to do this on the server. I could obviously configure another database to test, but really I don't see how that cold work and it doesn't. I really don't think that is supported.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I was referring to the `Log` property through Entity Framework. It's odd that EF wouldn't support this but Dapper does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can still build the parameters and include them in the parameterized query.

The query would look something like this when generated

```sql
UPDATE Messages SET Viewed = 1 WHERE Id IN (@p0, @p1, @p2, ..., @pn)
```

So given

```
IEnumerable<int> Ids;
```

Then

```
var parameters = Ids.Select((id, index) => new SqlParameter(string.Format("@p{0}", index), id));
var parameterNames = string.Join(", ", parameters.Select(p => p.ParameterName));
var query = string.Format("UPDATE Messages SET Viewed = 1 WHERE Id IN ({0})", parameterNames);

int affected = DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(query, parameters.ToArray());
```

Comment: I think this is a good answer but not the answer OP was looking for.

Comment: Interesting suggestion. Might be the best that you can do with `ExecuteSqlCommand`.

Comment: That is currently how I do it with EF. And I have searched for you requested for a really long time. I settled on this format when I saw it in some MS documentation.

Comment: @Nkosi: Obviously, there comes a point where it's so much more effort that it's not really any more efficient. But it looks like this would still be more efficient.

Comment: @Nkosi: So far, I'm getting an exception `System.ArgumentException: 'No mapping exists from object type System.Int32[] to a known managed provider native type.'`. Did you try the code?

Comment: Yes. I have this in production code. The second parameter is a `param object[]`

Comment: @Nkosi: Looks like you had the `(i, id)` parameters swapped, but I'm still getting the same error. Wonder what I have different.

Comment: @JonathanWood hold on let me go pull up that project and take a look.

Comment: @Nkosi: Any luck? I can't see what I'm doing that is different. It doesn't seem to accept an array for the `params` argument.

Comment: @JonathanWood I checked and it works for me. Also found another answer here where they do basically the same thing http://stackoverflow.com/a/25497384/5233410. I already had an up-vote on that answer so I guess I would have come across this in my research

Comment: @JonathanWood No I was referring to the article I link to in my last comment.

Comment: @Nkosi: Oh, you updated your answer to create an array of `SqlParameter`. That's the part I was missing (and what the other question you linked to does.)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of generating query string with exact values, you can generate query string with as many parameters as you have.
So you'll get smth like:

```
DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("UPDATE Messages SET Viewed = 1 WHERE Id IN (@p0,@p1,@p2,...,@pN)", Ids);
```

by smth like this:

```
var paramsDef = string.Concat(Ids.Select(x=>$"{(Ids.IndexOf(x) > 0 ? "," : "")}p{Ids.IndexOf(x)}"));            
DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand($"UPDATE Messages SET Viewed = 1 WHERE Id IN {paramsDef}", Ids);
```

Some links I found people doing similar with SqlCommand:
http://www.svenbit.com/2014/08/using-sqlparameter-with-sqls-in-clause-in-csharp/
http://nodogmablog.bryanhogan.net/2016/01/parameterize-sql-where-in-clause-c/