# WHERE IN Raw SQL Query used with ExecuteSqlCommand not working for multiple records

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework, dbcontext

I'm trying to make efficient use of a `UPDATE` query while updating multiple records (instead of looping for every `Id`).

I have this simple method:

```
    public static async Task EfficientlyUpdateSentTimeforSomeTicketsAsync(List<int> Ids)
    {
        var parameters = Ids.Select((id, index) => new SqlParameter(string.Format("@p{0}", index), id));
        var parameterNames = string.Join(", ", parameters.Select(p => p.ParameterName));
        var query = string.Format("Update [TicketQueueTable] Set SentDatetime = {1} WHERE TicketQueueID IN ({0})", parameterNames, DateTime.Now);

        try
        {
            using (var db = GetDbContext())
            {
                var affectedRows = await db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(query, parameters.ToArray());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await LogErrorAsync(ex);
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

I took help from this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43969812/8644294 but I'm unable to make this work. It hits me with exception that says:

> Incorrect syntax near '2'

For simplicity, the Ids that I'm sending for now is `new List<int>() { 1, 2 }`.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You should create a parameter for the date you want to set as well.  But the issue is that you format that date into the query without putting single quotes around it.

Comment: Hi @juharr , Sorry I didn't get it. Can you please elaborate? And when I put quotes around the Date, I'm getting exception: `No mapping exists from object type System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter[] to a known managed provider native type.`

Comment: Can you please show me the exact message that exception is throwing

Comment: you can't use parameters as inputs to elements of an in statement.  an in statement requires constants, instead use a values statement and construct a table which you link to

Comment: Try: `var query = string.Format("Update [TicketQueueTable] Set SentDatetime = NOW() WHERE TicketQueueID IN ({0})", parameterNames);`  always best to use the datetime on the sql server rather than the web server, especially once you start running more than one webserver.

Comment: I mean the SQL should be `SentDatetime = @SendDatetime` and you should create a parameter for it `new SqlParameter("@SendDatetime", DateTime.Now)`

Comment: @Hogan You can do stuff like `Blah in (@param1, @parm2)`  The down side is if you hit the parameter limit.

Comment: @juharr -- ah good to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string you are creating looks like this

```
Update [TicketQueueTable] Set SentDatetime = 3/6/2020 2:30:18 AM WHERE TicketQueueID IN (@p0, @p1)
```

If you try to execute that command using a sql tool like SQL Server Management Studio, you will get this error.

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '2'.
```

Plus the 2 in the 2:30:18 AM is underlined red.

---

You have a couple of options:

1. quote the date time

```
var query = string.Format("Update [TicketQueueTable] Set SentDatetime = '{1}' WHERE TicketQueueID IN ({0})", parameterNames, DateTime.Now);
```

2. use a sql function to get the current time of the sql server

```
var query = string.Format("Update [TicketQueueTable] Set SentDatetime = GETDATE() WHERE TicketQueueID IN ({0})", parameterNames, DateTime.Now); // GETDATE() for MSSQL NOW() for MySQL
```

3. pass the date time in as a parameter

```
public static async Task EfficientlyUpdateSentTimeforSomeTicketsAsync(List<int> Ids)
{
    var parameters = Ids.Select((id, index) => new SqlParameter(string.Format("@p{0}", index), id)).ToList();
    var parameterNames = string.Join(", ", parameters.Select(p => p.ParameterName));
    var query = string.Format("Update [TicketQueueTable] Set SentDatetime = @p{1} WHERE TicketQueueID IN ({0})", parameterNames, parameters.Count());

    parameters.Add(new SqlParameter($"@p{parameters.Count()}", DateTime.Now));
    try
    {
        using (var db = GetDbContext())
        {
            var affectedRows = await db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(query, parameters.ToArray());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await LogErrorAsync(ex);
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this great detailed answer!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:  (I didn't test, might have a typo)

```
var parameterNames = string.Join(", ", Ids.Select(p => "("+ x.id.ToString()+")"));
var query = string.Format(@"Update TicketQueueTable 
                              Set SentDatetime = '{1}'
                             FROM TicketQueueTable
                             JOIN (
                               VALUES
                                {0}
                             ) AS L(ID) ON TicketQueueTable.Ticket.TicketQueueID = L.ID;", parameterNames, DateTime.Now)
```

If you want to use a parameter (which you should) then make it a table parameter and have the list of values in the table and join to it.